# Restler framework exception handling

Tags: exception, restler

how can I write exception handling in my application. I am using restler framework

Answer (score 0):

RestException is handled by Restler framework to send a error response to the api user. Other than that Exception handling in restler is the usual PHP way

Best way to handle exceptions is to use [`try` `catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block where you expect them

You can detect un-handled exceptions and handle them using [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). Ideally you can do that at the index.php (gateway)